# Stack Columns where you Consult Column A, if there is a value print Column B, then stack Column C beneath it

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, multiple-columns

I am seeking a formula that will stack Columns B & C. I want to consult Column A, and where there is a value in Column A present the value in Column B (even if it is blank), and then stack Column C beneath it. Blank cells should remain blank.

Here is an image:
[image]

Here is the data set: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qcRUtXKJ6y21G3leRf9EQ98xB4oyViX_Mr2sqVvGs2c/edit

I would appreciate the help, as I cannot figure out how to add an IF statement to the Column Stacking. (If value exists in A, print B, then stack C.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `FILTER()` then `TOCOL()`.

```
=TOCOL(FILTER(B2:C,A2:A<>""),,1)
```

Or `VSTACK()` with `FILTER()`.

```
=VSTACK(FILTER(B2:B,A2:A<>""),FILTER(C2:C,A2:A<>""))
```

[image]